# Clear, gasoline resistant resin

Tags: resin

I’m wondering if there was a resin that could help me produce this: [image]

Some old carburetors from the 1960’s had glass bowls.  Well, I’d love one, but to find one on eBay it’d cost more than my engine.  Wondering if there’s a way to print a clear one

Comment: A quick search for "fuel resistant uv resin" turned up  https://www.liqcreate.com/supportarticles/chemical-compatibility-of-3d-printed-resin-parts/  . That said, this seems extraordinarily dangerous, as any failure would pretty much spray your legs with fuel.

Comment: I actually visited that site before posting, it seems like the only material listed there suited for gasoline was not clear. Well, with the possible exception of the bio-med clear, but that didnt seem as 'tough' and impact resistant as the others.  Which, as you said, would be a chief concern.
I do agree its probably not as safe as metal, but can't imagine its any LESS safe than glass.

Comment: @JosephCrozier Thick glass is surprisingly impact and wear resistant

Comment: Unlike plastic, glass is dimensionally stable, insoluble in gasoline, and won't fail "just a little" or "over time" the way plastic will.  If the glass were to fail, it would be due to a very hard impact that would probably also result in damage to more of the bike and rider.

Comment: This might be venturing outside the scope of stackexchange and be more of a 'forum' thing, but I'm not opposed to glass, but not sure how to fabricate something like that without exorbitant expense (at which point I'd just buy it).  I did xometry might be able to 3d print in silica glass, but despite the name, didn't actually appear clear.

Comment: If you can 3d print what you want, there's a good chance you can find somebody to make a mold and pour the glass for you.